# How can I added a text for one file to another files "Multi Text files"

Tags: dos

I'll be grateful If someone help me with below issue ,
I have one file hello.txt contained text "Hello all " and I want this text to be added with multi others files has text "this me" ,and first text to be above with each files :

hello.txt have text = "Hello all "
multi files 1.txt
            2.txt
            3.txt
            4.txt
            5.txt
            .
            .
           20.txt
and all has a text "this me"

-the result that I need
1.txt ..... 20.txt the text be "hello all this me"

How can i do this

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You can use the copy or xcopy dos commands to copy more than one text file to a third file. You can do this using a wildcard for the first (source) filename. For example, if you have two files in the current folder named test1.txt and test2.txt, you could copy the contents of the two files to a file called destination.txt with this command:

```
copy test?.txt destination.txt
```

If you need to do this with the files you mentioned above, you can make a .bat file with some rename commands to allow the copy to work with wildcards:

```
rename 1.txt hello2.text
copy hello?.text 1.txt 
del hello2.txt
```

You should make a backup copy of these files before you start, in case you make a mistake or it doesn't work like you expect.

Answer (score 0):

```
for /L %v in (1,1,20) do (
    for /F "tokens=*" %l in (hello.txt) do echo %l this is me > %v.txt
)
```